# how to use pandas isin function in 2d numpy array?

Tags: pandas, numpy, isin

I have created a 2d numpy array with 2 rows and 5 columns.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.zeros((2, 5))

arr[0] = [12, 94, 4, 4, 2]
arr[1] = [1, 3, 4, 12, 46]
```

I have also created a dataframe with two columns `col1` and `col2`

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [2,3,4,5,6]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list1, 'col2': list2})
```

I used pandas `isin` function with `col1` and `col2` to create a boolean value list, like this:

```
df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])
```

output

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
```

Now I want to use these bool values to slice the 2d array that I have created before, I can do that for a single row but now for the whole 2d array at once:

```
print(arr[0][df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])])
print(arr[1][df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])])
```

output:

```
[94.  4.  4.  2.]
[ 3.  4. 12. 46.]
```

but when I do something like this:

```
print(arr[df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])])
```

But this gives the error:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 5
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `arr[:, df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])]`? This selects all the rows first by `:` and then your bool series acts on which columns to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should slice on the second dimension of the array:

```
arr[:, df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])]
```

output:

```
array([[94.,  4.,  4.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4., 12., 46.]])
```